# Teamcity to run .exe file on remote server

Tags: windows, server, teamcity, psexec, windows-server

We have a build server with Teamcity. It should run an .exe file on a Windows Server 2012 r2 machine after building. I have wasted a day trying to make it work different ways. The last realisation is: .bat file calling an .exe with the needed parameters on a producion server and command line command in teamcity:

```
psexec -i \\server-ip C:/SharedFolder/RUNME.bat
```

This works perfectly from command line, but Teamcity shows different errors with exit codes 4, 6 or even doesn't do anything without an error.

How, HOW can I do it? Thanx.

Answer (score 0):

Solved, I just had to run TeamCity services as a domain administrator.